# update column by comparing two columns in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a pandas dataframe like below

```
Id Name PId Pname
------------------
01 Kiyl  -    -

02 Chery 04 Eden  

03 Daril -   -

04 Eden  01 Kiyil
```

Id, Name,PID are given columns in the dataframe. We need to for the PName column which is obtained by comparing the Pid with Id and fill out the name as PName for it. If PID is empty, then leave it.

Can anyone suggest efficient way to do this using Pandas

```
def fn_getparamname(row,df):
  #  i=i+1
  #  print(i)
    if(row['pid']==None):
        return ''
    indices=df.index[df['id']==row['pid']]
    if(len(indices)>0):
        print(indices)
    print(df.iloc[indices[0]]['name'])
    return df.iloc[indices[0]]['name']
return ''
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where others do your work for you. What have you tried? Have you written anything at all?

Comment: def fn_getparamname(row,df):
  #  i=i+1
  #  print(i)
    if(row['parentid']==None):
        return ''
    indices=df.index[df['id']==row['parentid']]
    if(len(indices)>0):
        print(indices)
        print(df.iloc[indices[0]]['name'])
        return df.iloc[indices[0]]['name']
    return ''

Comment: I know what is stackoverflow is. Dont take lessones for me. I just forgot to add my tried way of approach. @AlexanderCécile

Comment: That’s good, I was just checking. Unfortunately many people seem to think it is :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

First we create a dict of your `Id` and `Name` column with `Id` as the Key, and `Name` as the value.

```
id_name_dict = dict(zip(df['Id'],df['Name']))
print(id_name_dict)
{1: 'Kiyl', 2: 'Chery', 3: 'Daril', 4: 'Eden'}
```

#### We then take advantage of the Python `map`feature to map the values based on the `PId` column

```
df['PId'].map(id_name_dict)
0     NaN
1    Eden
2     NaN
3    Kiyl
Name: PId, dtype: object
```

you can then assign this to a column and fill the blank values with whatever value you want.

```
df['Pname'] = df['PId'].map(id_name_dict).fillna('-')
print(df)
           Id   Name PId Pname
    0   1   Kiyl   -     -
    1   2  Chery   4  Eden
    2   3  Daril   -     -
    3   4   Eden   1  Kiyl
```

Comment: Thanks It worked and it is faster way compared to what I mentioned

Comment: Thanks dinesh, happy coding!